# Instagram API Tag

Tags: jquery, instagram-api

Que tal compañeros, vengo con un problema que me tiene loco, y es que estoy utilizando la API de instagram para obtener fotos mediante un hashtag, lo que sucede es que funcionaba normalmente hasta hace unos días, y hoy me llevo la sorpresa que ya no funciona más. Borre la aplicación de Instagram y volví a crear otra.

Utilice la siguiente cadena para generar el TOKEN con permisos varios...

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={CLIENTE ID}&redirect_uri={URL-REDIRECCION}&response_type=token&scope=basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo esto, pensé que ya había obtenido todo...

Pero oh sorpresa... me sale lo siguiente:

> deprecation_warning:"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this
>   endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"

Adjunto el código que estaba utilizando

HTML

```
<div id="instagram"></div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <!-- button -->
    <div id="showMore">
        <div class='clearfix '><a id='more' next_url='"+next_url+"' href='#'>[Load More]</a></div>      
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var access_token = "TOKEN";
var resolution = "thumbnail"; 
var hashtag = "life";
var last_url = "";
var start_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/"+hashtag+"/media/recent?access_token="+access_token;

function loadEmUp(next_url){

    console.log("loadEmUp url:" + next_url);
    url = next_url;

    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                url: url,
                success: function(data) {

                next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
                count = 20; 
                //console.log("count: " + count );
                console.log("next_url: " + next_url );
                console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data) );

                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        if (typeof data.data[i] !== 'undefined' ) {
                        //console.log("id: " + data.data[i].id);
                            $("#instagram").append("<div class='instagram-wrap' id='pic-"+ data.data[i].id +"' ><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><span class='likes'>"+data.data[i].likes.count +"</span><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>"
                        );  
                        }  
                }     

                //console.log("next_url: " + next_url);
                $("#showMore").hide();
                if (typeof next_url === 'undefined' || next_url.length < 10 ) {
                    console.log("NO MORE");
                    $("#showMore").hide();
                    $( "#more" ).attr( "next_url", "");
                }


                else {
                    console.log("displaying more");
                    $("#showMore").show();
                    $( "#more" ).attr( "next_url", next_url);
                    last_url = next_url;

                }
            }
        });
    });
}




$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#more" ).click(function() {  
        var next_url = $(this).attr('next_url');
        loadEmUp(next_url);
        return false;
    });

    loadEmUp(start_url);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal compañeros, se que esta pregunta abunda mucho en internet, el procedimiento que he utilizado es el adecuado y no tiene nada que ver con:

> deprecation_warning:"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"

Sigue funcionando, aunque esto nada mas es una advertencia de que los parametros estan en desuso y no tiene nada que ver con el problema que tenemos.

**La solución:**

La parte importante se encuentra en el token que generamos, al utilizar las sentencias que comente en la pregunta:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={CLIENTE ID}&redirect_uri={URL-REDIRECCION}&response_type=token&scope=basic+public_content+follower_list+comments+relationships+likes
```

Esto hace una autorización de "nosotros hacia nosotros" por así decirlo, pero llámenme loco... xD he encontrado y recorrido casi 30 paginas de google que he encontrado una página que hace una autorización hacia nuestro token, haciendo que este obtenga permisos hacia nosotros para nuestra aplicación. Es algo raro pero funciona.

Adjunto el [enlace aquí](http://axentmedia.com/instagram-access-token/) para quien tenga el mismo problema, obviamente para poder utilizarlo hay que hacer los pasos que siguen en el siguiente [enlace](http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token)

Y en la api dice esto:

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).
>   You can find more information in the Permission Review documentation.

Comment: Este metodo sigue funcionando? Ya que las reglas han cambiado en la API de Instagram y necesito hacer algo similar.

Comment: puedes ver la api de instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/ e intentar lo que comenté. Después si te sale algún error puedes hacer una pregunta en stackoverflow o resolverla si es que es algo sencillo